# Can a PC that played only part of ToA be resurrected in a later adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, tomb-of-annihilation, resurrection

I have a doubt regarding the Death Curse.
I played part of the Tomb of Annihilation (ToA) HC with one of my characters, then decided to exit it and wait out.
After this she died in another T2 adventure (Season 2, not ToA).

Her companion brought her corpse back to the city, so my question is: can she resurrect?

Comment: I'm confused on how exactly the character managed to die twice. Doesn't the fact that you died again after the tomb of annihilation campaign imply that the character was already revived inbetween?

Comment: My bad, she only died once. 
After played part of the ToA HC (she didn't die while in there) decided to wait out.  After this she played the other T2 adventure and died during this adventure.

Comment: Please spell out the acronyms in your question (ToA, HC, T2) so it's clearer for people who aren't familiar with those terms.

Comment: @Marq If they aren't familiar with these terms they *probably* aren't able to give an appropriate AL answer, to be honest...

Comment: @HellSaint A Stack Exchange site exists to be read as a resource; all of the questions should be as readable as possible. It's not just about catering to potential question answerers, since the people who view questions without answering them or commenting are vastly more numerous.

Comment: @Marq On the other hand, we shouldn’t eliminate domain-specific jargon either, because that makes searching for that specific jargon impossible. “HC”, “T2” are AL jargon and should be left alone. (For example, “HC” means “hardcover” — ironically it is *less* meaningful spelled out, because only in jargon-y “HC” form does it carry any meaning relevant to AL.) ToA should be expanded and also included in acronym form for searchability.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie comment made me create this Q&A: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130125/43856 - I think we shouldn't be spelling out common terms, just as we don't spell out D&D. SE is a format **for "experts"**, and, IMO, understanding common terms is part of that expertise, proven by the fact that we have a [tag:terminology] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DDAL DM Guide states, for resurrection:

> ***Death***. A character who dies during the course of the adventure has a few options **at the end of the session (or when arriving back in civilization during the adventure)** [...]
>   No matter the means of death, bodies (and its possessions) are considered recoverable by friends and allies unless otherwise specified.

So, yes, she can be resurrected **during the adventure** if she was brought back to city. She can also be resurrected even if not - just wait for the end of the *session*.

The text then proceeds to describe what the player can do - paying for being resurrected, the party paying for it, the faction doing it as a favor or simply creating another 1st level character. These are also important to log, since the character is losing some gp there.

About the ToA Death Curse:

> "Any character can choose to be rid of the curse by: [...] Waiting It Out. Alternatively, characters can wait until others have done their dirty work by retiring from adventuring **until the release of Season 7’s Tier 3 adventures (January 2018)**, or by starting any Tier 3 or 4 non-hardcover (non-DDHC) adventure, and resuming adventuring following Acererak’s defeat. *A character choosing this option can’t play Tomb of Annihilation, or any Season 7 Tier 1 or 2 adventures—with or without a surrogate*; these doors to adventure are forever closed to them."

Thanks to @T.J.L. for the correction - the curse is still active for ToA and S7 T1 and T2 adventures. When she "Waited it out", she got rid of the curse (as stated in the beginning of the text):

> Any character can choose to be rid of the curse by [...]

As the curse no longer affects her, she  can be resurrected, but, as from the *emphasized* part, she won't be able to play ToA, S7 T1 or S7 T2 adventures with that character.

Comment: During ToA you can't be revived, the death curse would prevent that. I do not have enough knowledge of DnD adventurers league to answer how this interacts with other campaigns though.

Comment: More info about the Death Curse in ToA in AL here: https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/ToAPrimerv1.pdf

Comment: Regarding OP "waiting it out", it says: "Any character can choose to be rid of the curse by: [...] ***Waiting It Out.*** Alternatively, characters can wait until others have done their dirty work by retiring from adventuring until the release of Season 7’s Tier 3 adventures (January 2018), or by starting any Tier 3 or 4 non-hardcover (non-DDHC) adventure, and resuming adventuring following Acererak’s defeat. A character choosing this option can’t play Tomb of Annihilation, or any Season 7 Tier 1 or 2 adventures—with or without a surrogate; these doors to adventure are forever closed to them.""

Comment: @V2Blast You have an answer in there. I think if you post it it will be very helpful.

Comment: @Theik Added the clarification on that part. That was a temporary event and is no longer active.

Comment: @HellSaint The Death Curse still applies to characters playing S7 T1, S7 T2, and ToA itself. Taking the "Wait It Out" option bars characters from participating in that content, but it does not remove the Death Curse from that content.

Comment: @T.J.L. Corrected that - it was a misreading from me. It doesn't affect the resurrecting part, but affects that she won't be able to play these adventures any more.

Comment: @HellSaint Not unheard of... The Death Curse Primer is pretty poorly written. :(